# Add elements of dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks the like the following

```py
output_dict = {"weight_1": [1, 2, 3], "weight_2": [4, 5, 6]}
```

I want the to have a result list which looks like this

```py
results_list = [5, 7, 9]
```

This also needs to work for n amount of weights, so for example if we had

```py
output_dict = {"weight_1": [1, 2, 3], "weight_2": [4, 5, 6], "weight_3": [7, 8, 9]}
```

The output would be

```py
results_list = [12, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` the dictionary values and then `sum` them:

```
[sum(vals) for vals in zip(*output_dict.values())]
```

Alternatively with `map`:

```
[*map(sum, zip(*output_dict.values()))]
```